# axis 1.4 - how to exclude nilllable elements

Tags: java, axis

I have such element declaration in XSD schema:

```
<xsd:element name="someelement" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
```

Axis 1.4 serializes empty (null) value like that:

```
 <someelement xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

My question is: is it possible to omit such "empty" elements from result XML generated by Axis?

Comment: Seems that I found the reason of this behaviour. Axis 1.4 adds this if service description in WSDL declares to use SOAP encoding. When I removed SOAP Encoding declaration - the problem was solved

Comment: It would be great if you can elaborate the fix you have applied